# 'Converting' file into directory

Tags: encryption, data-recovery, directory

Long story short: I have all my files in my home folder **encrypted**, somehow, I managed to delete a very important folder. Thankfully, I was able to recover all my information with *extundelete*. However, all the folders that I've recovered now show up as files, leaving me without access to the files in those folders.

Taking into account that all my home folder is encrypted (making things more difficult to recover from a LiveCD/USB), is it possible to change the 'flags' of a folder/file in order to restore access to the files inside that folder?

Comment: I have never done something like this, but there's `debugfs` command, that maybe something that will start you on the right path.